# Glow effect shader for mesh generated at runtime

Tags: unity, shaders, glsl

I'm using the leap motion-paint module and i would like the ribbons that are generated at runtime to have a glow effect, I tried editing the existing shader by adding a glow property but the colors did not change. I'm not experienced with shaders so any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I tried adding post-processing effects for bloom & glows, all the objects have a glow effect except the ones i'm generating at runtime..

```
 Shader "LeapMotion/TubeShader" {


Properties{
    _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
     _Glow("Intensity", Range(0, 3)) = 1
  }
  SubShader{
    Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" "Glowable"="True"}
    LOD 200
CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows
#pragma target 3.0

struct Input {
  float4 color : COLOR;
};

half _Glossiness;
half _Metallic;
fixed4 _Color;
half _Glow;

void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
  o.Albedo = (_Color* _Glow * IN.color).rgb * ;
  o.Metallic = _Metallic;
  o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
}
ENDCG

}
  FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Are you currently using any post-processing effects for bloom & glows?

Comment: I'm not using any because i thought it will have an effect on all the objects in the scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking a bit further into it, i made some adjustments and it works, I needed to add some tags, edit the way i was changing the albedo and add post-processing effects for bloom.
Here's the code if anyone's facing the same problem.

```
 Shader "LeapMotion/TubeShader" {
  Properties{
    _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
     _Glow("Intensity", Range(0, 3)) = 1
  }
  SubShader{
    Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Glowable"="True"}
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows
    #pragma target 3.0

    struct Input {
      float4 color : COLOR;
    };

    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
    fixed4 _Color;
    half _Glow;

    void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
     o.Albedo = (_Color + _Glow * IN.color).rgb;
      o.Metallic = _Metallic;
      o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
    }
    ENDCG
  }
  FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```